# Can an improperly attached ledger board be flashed correctly without removing the existing ledger?

Tags: decking

I have a existing improperly installed deck attached to the house which I am retrofitting. I already have a permit approved but not sure how to flash the existing ledger board without removing the entire structure. Is there a way to flash this to keep out moisture? Currently there are parts that are attached with a ledger and some that is not.

Comment: How about posting a picture of this.

Comment: I have found decks that were not flashed at all ( water ingress causing problems) I used a flexible heavy foil to flash by cutting the siding sliding the foil up inside. My first step was to remove the first deck board and rip it so the flashing could hang over the ledger and down a couple of inches. I originally tried with standard flashing but it was just about impossible to get it in place , the foil allowed me to form it at each hanger this did stop the water problem and after painting it did not look bad but was easier than taking the entire deck down and doing it correctly.

Comment: Thanks Ed, do you know of the product name or where to source Flexible Heavy Foil? This procedure is one I was considering although I have thick older clapboard. I am not sure how difficult it would be to do this. I may give it a try though!

Answer (score 0):

@trebor nirom , sorry I did not see your comment was going through old questions and found it.  One product I have used is “cop-r-shield” it is thin copper some what easy to form but more expensive than the “tight seal” aluminum flashing tape that I regularly have used. The aluminum is thin so if poked with a stick it can be punctured I pressed it tight up under the siding and down the wall then over the ledger. It lasts and did the job on that deck , no more water getting in the walls. The copper cost ~40$ for a roll and the aluminum is ~10$ other than one of my kids poking holes in a section it has held up for close to 20 years. Where the holes were poked through I added another layer about 6” wider on each side, it will stick to itself.

Comment: Ed,  Thanks for your reply. I will look into it. Do you know if "Cop-r-Shield " is readily available? As it stands now I am at the point where I will need to either remove the existing improperly attached ledger board and make this a free standing deck or find another way to address the rot and stop it from progressing! As a side note, I would advise anyone facing this to start over and just build new! My attempt to save cash is way more work than its worth and may not produce solid results.

Comment: Yes I know Home Depot and Jerry’s have carried it. The last roll I ordered on line ~6 months ago.

Comment: Okay I am going to check it out-thanks!